# Custom Code for Color Gradation in SSRS header

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016, ssrs-2017

I'm trying to make SSRS custom report header. Refereed this link:

http://sqljason.com/2013/02/custom-code-for-color-gradation-in-ssrs.html

How can I put below color as my report header. Note: I would like to display the text, date and sum of count dynamically as well.

Specially looking for color attached below as my header color: 
[image]

Do I need to write some custom code for header? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could just create an image with the gradient in using one of many free image editors around. Then use that image in a rectangle in your header. You can then add the data as textboxes in the rectangle.

Be warned some rendered do not like overlapping objects so do a quick test and check in each of the desired output formats before you spend too much time on the report.